# Steganography - Is there a more smart/complex way for hiding files ?

Tags: image, file, zip, hidden, steganography

**So, by far every tutorial I've seen regarding this topic either for linux or windows, are including the compressing of files and putting them inside an image, and by so creating a new one containing these files.

--
A zip file appended to a jpg file can be easily detected. With a little analysis you can easily understand that the jpg file has some extra information at the end, and you can recognize the header of a zip file after the normal jpeg data (even if the zip file is encrypted)
Question is, is there a bit more smarter/complex method for hiding files inside an image ?
thnx for any help.**

Comment: It is not simple like appending file to another file at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography_tools

Comment: Sure it is not as simple, but when it comes to actully hiding files I suppose more efficiently , I am looking for more complex ways.

Comment: I don't know what tutorials you've been reading, but I'm surprised you haven't come across with the [lsb substitution method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Example_from_modern_practice). Now, take this idea an apply it to DCT or DWT coefficients, or some other transform, or some other way of deciding how your embedded 1s and 0s will reconstruct the secret. You can make it as complex as you want. A simple search on Google Scholar for steganograpy you will provide you with enough material for ages. So, the answer is yes, there are more complex methods.

Answer (score 0):

Steganography can be done in 3 domains; the spatial, frequency and compressed domain. Each of these domains have their pros and cons.

For example, in the compressed domain, you can hide a large secret in a compressed image and it will be very difficult to detect as the binary stream is what will be transmitted from sender to receiver. However, in the spatial domain, the existence of a secret message becomes easier to detect as the natural image is transferred as a whole.

There are many new steganographic algorithms being published in journals each month, you can look at the top journals in this field (such as IEEE, or Information Sciences) to find a suitable technique.